# Custom component in Streamlit is having trouble loading

Tags: python, typescript, streamlit

I'm testing out a custom [authentication component](https://github.com/mstaal/msal_streamlit_authentication) for my Streamlit app. However, when using the component in production, it fails to render for some reason.
[image]

I've managed to get i to work in dev mode by forking the code and adding it to my Streamlit project - but I still can't make it run in production.

Upon digging a bit, it seems to me that the declaration of the component fails since the build path for some reason doens't work. It looks like the assertion fails since the module is none as per the following traceback

```
venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\components\v1\components.py:284, in declare_component(name, path, url)
    281 # Get the caller's module name. `__name__` gives us the module's
    282 # fully-qualified name, which includes its package.
    283 module = inspect.getmodule(caller_frame)
--> 284 assert module is not None
...
    288 # user executed `python my_component.py`), then this name will be
    289 # "__main__" instead of the actual package name. In this case, we use
    290 # the main module's filename, sans `.py` extension, as the component name.

AssertionError:
```

To obtain the `build_path` I use the following:

```
root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
build_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, "frontend" , "dist")
```

This returns:

```
'c:\\Users\\initials\\xxx\\Desktop\\Absence importer\\absense_importer\\frontend\\dist'
```

The component is declared like this:

```
_USE_WEB_DEV_SERVER = os.getenv("USE_WEB_DEV_SERVER", False)
_WEB_DEV_SERVER_URL = os.getenv("WEB_DEV_SERVER_URL", "http://localhost:5173")
COMPONENT_NAME = "msal_authentication"


root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
build_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, "frontend" , "dist")

if _USE_WEB_DEV_SERVER:
    _component_func = components.declare_component(name=COMPONENT_NAME, url=_WEB_DEV_SERVER_URL)
else:
    _component_func = components.declare_component(name=COMPONENT_NAME, path=build_dir)
```

I've also tried to wrap everything inside a Linux Docker container, but to no avail, unfortunately. Can anyone spot my error?

I'm on Python 3.10.7 and using Streamlit 1.18.1.

**EDIT*:*

Figured out my browswer has issues reading the compiled frontend code, due to a mismatch in MIME types. I'm not sure, what's wrong. By either adding the MIME types manually like

```
import mimetypes 

mimetypes.add_type('application/javascript', '.js') 
mimetypes.add_type('text/css', '.css')
```

Or using the [sample-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75533746/custom-component-in-streamlit-is-having-trouble-loading/75737109#75737109) from the author worked.

[image]

Comment: I am facing same problem. Where should I add these mimetype imports?

Comment: After importing packages should do.

Comment: Just for future reference: I tried this and it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: For future reference: I've had streamlit component defined in the same file. And I've got this error (module not found) on second run. Reason: exception thrown when page is run, so module with component is **not properly initialized**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of said custom Streamlit Component, and I have made [a small sample project](https://github.com/mstaal/streamlit_msal_sample) that utilizes the component. I just ran the project in Docker, and it works for me. I have yet to discover what can cause the troubles on Windows.

Essentially, the sample project is just a barebone Streamlit dashboard consisting of the following script.

```
import streamlit as st

from msal_streamlit_authentication import msal_authentication


token_response = msal_authentication(
    auth={
        "clientId": "aaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeee",
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeee",
        "redirectUri": "/",
        "postLogoutRedirectUri": "/"
    },
    cache={
        "cacheLocation": "sessionStorage",
        "storeAuthStateInCookie": False
    },
    login_request={
        "scopes": ["yyyyyy-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeee/.default"]
    },
    key=1)
st.write("Received", token_response)
```

You should insert clientId, tenant/authority and scope values in accordance with your situation. Note that my test is based on the Authorization Code (PKCE) flow.

Comment: Made it work using the sample project. Not sure what caused the error, but I think it might be related specifically to my PC.

Comment: I find it's often a neworking error when deployed on Docker containers in Azure Container Apps or GCP Cloud Run

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there might be an issue with this component -- have you considered filing an issue? https://github.com/mstaal/msal_streamlit_authentication/issues

If that doesn't work, I would try looking in that folder in the build_dir variable and seeing if there is anything in there (e.g. an index.html and some JS files). If not, perhaps the code that finds the build_dir needs to be changed.

If there is content in that folder, than there may be an issue causing it to not be supported in Windows, which would probably require some deeper digging into the component code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up doing a bunch of digging and found a sort of hack-ish way of fixing this. The Streamlit server uses a guess mimetype functionality, which apparently isn't too accurate? At least, for my case it wasn't able to give the correct response header. So I simply ended up adding this to my main script `import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('application/javascript', '.js')
mimetypes.add_type('text/css', '.css')`

Comment: @Artem: I happen to be the author of the component, and I have not had the issue you are describing. I would very much like to fix it if you can provide me with some details on how you reproduce it (a sample dashboard project, your OS, which version of the library you use, ...)

Comment: Btw: I actually build the build_dir using pathlib, so the code would be:
build_dir = str(Path(__file__).parent / "frontend" / "dist")

Comment: @zachary-blackwood: Did you manage to reproduce the error yourself since you claim it does not work?

Comment: @mstaal I didn't mean to say it didn't work for me, just that it apparently wasn't working for the user, and trying to provide debugging steps based on their reported logs.